# How do we check which application launch another application?

Tags: virus-removal

Recently, I got banned from my hotmail account because hotmail says I have been sending too many 1 links emails.

I suspected it was probably a virus and ran a few virus scans with a few popular anti virus softwares (uninstalling one before installing another) but none of it was detected.

Either way I recovered my hotmail account and changed my password. Then I'm noticing something which is, after closing msn messenger manually sometime during the day msn messenger get launched again about 30 minutes to a few hours later, and I wonder that is a result of some bad application trying to launch msn messenger to send bad emails (or whatever you called it)

Is there any way I could do to find out which application is launching msn messenger without me manually launching it? Since the anti viruses doesn't seem to be able to do a good job.

Answer (score 0):

You could use hijackthis to look at all your processes.

What I suggest instead is using a live disk virus scanner. They have their own operating system and thus a rootkit can not interfere with your scanner.

My favorite one is [kaspersky rescue disk](http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/rescuedisk).